Relation of field of force to potential energy
I was reading I. E. Irodov's Fundamental laws of Mechanics.
On page 84 , in a section named Potential energy and force of a field, he writes
$$\mathbf{F}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}=-\mathrm{d}U \\ \implies F_s\mathrm{d}s=-\mathrm{d}U \\ \implies F_s=-\frac{\partial{U}}{\partial{s}}.$$
I do not understand from where the partial derivatives came into play.(Although I do know a bit about partial derivatives, they are derivatives of function with respect to more than one variables analogous to how a surface changes on going to $x$ and $y$ directions. That is all I know.)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

According to the multivariable chain rule the total differential of a multivariate function, for example $f(x,y)$, is:
$$\mathrm df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\mathrm dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\mathrm dy$$
If you have an equation $\mathrm df = a\mathrm dx + b\mathrm dy$ then by linear independence of $\mathrm dx$ and $\mathrm dy$ you must have
\begin{align*}
&a = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \\
&b = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\end{align*}
So in your case $\mathrm dU = -F_s\mathrm ds$ means that as the coefficient of $\mathrm ds$,
$$-F_s = \frac{\partial U}{\partial s}$$
I'm unsure of what other variables $U$ depends on, but just as a side note you know that the partial derivatives of $U$ with respect to them are all $0$ because they do not appear in the expression of $\mathrm dU$.

Could you please expand a bit on that 'multivariable chain rule'. I am a high school student and as such I only want to know the intuition behind it instead of formal rigour(like those pi epsilon things). Thank you .

@AryanKr. The first equation is the definition of the partial derivative, just like how $\mathrm{d}f = (\mathrm{d}f/\mathrm{d}x)\mathrm{d}x$ is a definition of the ordinary derivative $\mathrm{d}f/\mathrm{d}x$.
